# Is ubuntu switching to nouveau?

Tags: 11.04, nouveau

Driver application in natty offers a free nvdia driver, and it works with compiz and unity. Will natty be able to use nouveau and gallium,

Answer (score 2):

No, we still only use nouveau for 2D rendering and if you install the nvidia driver it will take over. New in natty though, you can now install libgl1-mesa-dri-experimental to get the experimental 3D driver. However, this is very much "if it breaks you get to keep both pieces", the developers don't want to get bug reports about it right now.

Answer (score 0):

It isn't a case of switching, `nouveau` is maturing in the kernel and it will be automatically selected by the kernel if no other driver is available.

But the binary `nvidia` driver is still preferred. It offers more features and better performance. Jockey should still prompt you to install it.

Comment: -1 It is a case of switching. It's whether `nouveau` will replace the old `nv` as the default open source driver.

Comment: @fluteflute Maverick already uses `nouveau` as the default. This isn't a switch.